# Error after installing Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, lenovo

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Lenovo G580.
So everything went alright, then I installed Kubuntu to try it out, and it was pretty laggy then I uninstalled it so everything got messed up and I got confused, So I just decided to format Ubuntu and install it again.
After I installed it and rebooted, I got an error message saying: "Ubuntu is blocked by the current security policy.".
Can I get some helps?

Comment: When you re-isntalled Ubuntu, did you format your drives?  You want to make sure to format the drives/partitions so that you can start completely fresh and clean :D.

Comment: Woah I'm not sure about it, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preface

I believe that you are installing Ubuntu over an existing installation, without cleaning up/re-partitioning your HDD/SSD.

### Formating Partitions using LiveCD

You can do the following in Ubuntu's LiveCD after installing **gparted**, but I prefer to use [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php).  At the time of writting, you must burn this image to a CD/DVD or use *the lateset* [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), which is not available in the repositories.

#### Installing gparted on Ubuntu LiveCD

1. Open a terminal

   - Press the Windows (Super) key.
   - Type 'Terminal' and select 'Terminal'
2. Install gparted

   - `sudo apt-get install gparted`

#### Formatting your partitions

1. Boot into LiveCD
2. Fire up gparted
3. Find the HDD/SSD with your Ubuntu installation
4. Delete all non-essential partitions (**don't remove any partitions that could contain data you need later**).
5. Reboot into Ubuntu's LiveCD
6. Install Ubuntu on your fresh freespace.

Comment: You mean I boot the LiveCD then click try Ubuntu and then install gparted? or how?

Comment: I have updated my answer to help better explain how to install gparted.

Comment: So I ran gparted (installed by defaults already). and I can tell that I have 4 partitions which are /dev/sda1(3.62mb used out of 94mb), /dev/sda2(10.65Gb used out of 459gb), /dev/sda3(none used out of 5.87Gb) and an unallocated partition(none used out of 1.02MB). What to do now?

Comment: If your drive does *not* contain sensitive/important information, you will want to delete each of the partitions.  Once they are deleted, you can run the Ubuntu installer and give it a try.

Comment: I don't have any sensitive information. thanks for your help :D